# What is the use of modulus in complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

The modulus of the complex number $z = a + bi$ is denoted by $|z|$ and is given by $|z| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

What is the meaning of this? What is a modulus?

Comment: The distance from a complex number to zero- think Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: Modulus of a complex number is its length. For the meaning of modulus: from Latin, literally "measure."

Answer (score 0):

A complexe number $z=a+ib$ is a point $ M$ in the plane $\Bbb R^2$. the coordinates of the point $ M $ are $(a,b)$.

the modulus of $ z$ represents the Euclidian distance between the point $M(a,b)$ and the origin $O(0,0)$.

$$d(O,M)=||\vec{OM}||=\sqrt{(a-0)^2+(b-0)^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=|z|$$

Comment: Dixon, in addition to @hamam_Abdallah's excellent explanation, think about this as comparable to the $\textbf{magnitude}$ of a vector.